# How I directly pass the checkbox value to database as a bit

Tags: c#, sql

I have one checkbox control in my web application.And i Connected with the sql server.I declared checkbox datatype as bit. when i am checked the checkbox control it needs to pass bit value.I already execute by following method.

```
int active;

if (chkboxActive.Checked)

{ active = 1; } 

else

{ active = 0; }

cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = active;
```

It executes well.But i felt it is not a efficient one. Give any other easiest code in short line.

Comment: `cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkboxActive.Checked;`

Comment: there is no definition for chkboxActive.value. It doesn't have a property like value. this type of error is shown

Comment: Yea my bad, changed it to `Checked`.

Comment: ya..this is working fine... thanks a lot

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@active", SqlDbType.Bit).Value = chkboxActive.Checked;
```

Comment: One another question. Is possible to send a opposite value.
for example
checked=0
unchecked=1

Comment: You can use `!chkboxActive.Checked` for that.

Comment: I have same issue but I want to pass the current value like if checked then pass 1 if unchecked pass 0 how ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Object Relational Mapping, you will be using a property to pass the value:

```
public bool Active {get; set;}
```

When you want to save your data to SQL database table for the BIT data type that will be passed from a `checkbox` you must set the parameters of the sql command to accept bool as bit data and convert it to `1 if true` or `0 if false` like this:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(SqlString, SqlConnection);
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Active", SqlDbType.Bit, Active ? 1:0).Value = Active;
```

So when the boolean value is passed from the `checkbox` to the 'Sql Variable` it will be converted to 1 or 0 based on the checkbox.checked property.

```
xData.Active = CheckBox.Checked;
```